# How do I deliver an email stuck in my Postfix mail queue?

Tags: linux, email, centos, ipv6, postfix

How do I send this email from Postfix? I am using CentOS release 6.8 running Postfix 2.6.6.

#### maillog

```
Jan 16 21:23:16 ip-172-99-99-99 postfix/smtp[17128]: connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Jan 16 21:23:16 ip-172-99-99-99 postfix/smtp[17128]: connect to aspmx2.googlemail.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c06::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Jan 16 21:23:16 ip-172-99-99-99 postfix/smtp[17128]: connect to aspmx3.googlemail.com[2607:f8b0:4002:c03::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Jan 16 21:23:16 ip-172-99-99-99 postfix/smtp[17128]: connect to aspmx5.googlemail.com[2607:f8b0:400c:c11::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Jan 16 21:23:16 ip-172-99-99-99 postfix/smtp[17128]: connect to aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c04::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Jan 16 21:23:16 ip-172-99-99-99 postfix/smtp[17128]: A3AEE2026D: to=<support+b78fd7ef-a67e-410e-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx@heroku.com>, relay=none, delay=361752, delays=361752/0.04/0.28/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400e:c04::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

#### Queue

```
# postqueue -p
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
A3AEE2026D     9899 Thu Jan 12 16:54:04  chloe@example.com
(connect to aspmx4.googlemail.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c0b::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
                                         support+b78fd7ef-a67e-410e-xxxx-xxxxxxx@heroku.com

-- 11 Kbytes in 1 Request.
```

#### Ping

```
# ping alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
PING alt1.aspmx.l.google.com (74.125.202.26) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from io-in-f26.1e100.net (74.125.202.26): icmp_seq=1 ttl=32 time=50.7 ms
```

Comment: Can you try ping6 instead of just ping? It seems there are problems with your ipv6 connection.

Comment: `# ping6 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com
connect: Network is unreachable`. `ifconfig`: `inet6 addr: fe80::8f1:cff:fe13:xxxxx/64 Scope:Link`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`postqueue -f` is generally used to flush the queue, after the root cause of the delivery failure is solved.

```
-f     Flush the queue: attempt to deliver all queued mail.

       This option implements the traditional "sendmail -q" command, by
       contacting the Postfix qmgr(8) daemon.

       Warning: flushing undeliverable mail frequently will  result  in
       poor delivery performance of all other mail.
```

`postqueue -i` can be used for a specific message:

```
-i queue_id
      Schedule  immediate delivery of deferred mail with the specified
      queue ID.

      This option implements the traditional sendmail -qI command,  by
      contacting the flush(8) server.

      This feature is available with Postfix version 2.4 and later.
```

If you have a permanent IPv6 outage, you may disable IPv6 in postfix with `inet_protocols`.

From http://www.postfix.org/IPV6_README.html :

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    # You must stop/start Postfix after changing this parameter.
    inet_protocols = ipv4       (DEFAULT: enable IPv4 only)
    inet_protocols = all        (enable IPv4, and IPv6 if supported)
    inet_protocols = ipv4, ipv6 (enable both IPv4 and IPv6)
    inet_protocols = ipv6       (enable IPv6 only)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  It was set to `inet_protocols = all`.  Now it sends:    `Jan 18 16:49:04 ip-172-31-15-65 postfix/smtp[6461]: C71C42026D: to=<support+b78fd7ef-a67e-410e-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx@heroku.com>, relay=alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[173.194.219.27]:25, delay=1.6, delays=0.65/0.09/0.24/0.64, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1484757944 x4si232979ybh.76 - gsmtp)`